# Is there exists any general formula for shortest area of triangle with integeral sides where, perimeter is given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, triangles, area

if the perimeter of triangle is given , then, how to find the shortest area of triangle with integral sides.
Let, $P$ be perimeter and $s$ be semi-perimeter.
 we known,$s=P/2$

area of  triangle $=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$

$\implies $  area of  triangle = $\frac{\sqrt{p(p-2a)(p-2b)(p-2c)}}{4}$

this equation contains four variables $a,b,c,P$. by using relation $P=a+b+c$ we can make the equation contains  three independent variables.

area of  triangle = $\frac{\sqrt{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)}}{4}$

then how to I continue?

Comment: Minimizing $A$ is equivalent to minimizing $A^2$, which is a polynomial. That simplifies things.

Comment: This looks like a problem to be solved by Lagrange multipliers, but that works with Real numbers, not integers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: We know that the locus of a point the sum of its distance to two fixed points, constant is ellipse. suppose a(front side to angle A)  coincides on the line  $F_1 F_2$ , connecting foci. then area of triangle is zero when A locates on vertex on major axis and it is maximum when it locates on co-vertex. How can we estimate minimum area?

Comment: Hint: Define (non-negative) integers $$u:=-a+b+c \qquad v := a- b + c \qquad w :=  a+b-c$$ and note that $u+v+w = a+b+c=p$. Since $$16\cdot\text{area}^2 = puvw$$ your task reduces to minimizing $uvw$ subject to $u+v+w=p$.